# Resizing images without PHP GD Library

Tags: php, image, gd

Is there other method for resizing images (pixels and KB/MB) and do simple tasks without the GD Library? Can't images be resized with css/jquery ? 
I'm starting a new project and they told me to use GD for this, I'm just wondering if there are others alternative client/side because I don't know GD Library and time is short for the project, so I'll lose some time to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Imagine](http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) PHP library sf the easiest I've worked with - it can use GD, Imagick, or GMagick to resize/crop images.

```
<?php
$imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
$size    = new Imagine\Image\Box(40, 40);
$imagine->open('/path/to/large_image.jpg')
    ->thumbnail($size, Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET)
    ->save('/path/to/thumbnail.png');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to be very quick to process your images, I suggest you to use the [Linux convert](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm) command.

```
$source = escapeshellarg($pathToOriginalPicture);
$target = escapeshellarg($pathToThumbnail);
exec("convert $source -resize 40x40 $target");
```

Never forget to escape your arguments using [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of image resizers and croppers for client-side using javascript and css. But if you want to save resized image on server side, you have to use GD or Imagick. Otherway, you can make your own image format reader and operate images the way you want.

Comment: The thing is all images come from cameras, so they are all 3000+ pixels and I need to resize them for the website for thumbnails, slideshow, albums and so on, so in multiple sizes but keeping the aspect-ratio (if it's called that way). Can you suggest me something easier than GD because I need to learn it fast having very short time